# Posting an array of JavaScript Objects and Mapping to Java Domain in Spring Controller Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying to write an ajax post request that hits a Spring Controller method and delivers some request params, one of which is an array of JavaScript objects: vendorBillingDetails. These JavaScript objects have a matching Java domain class and I would like to map them to this domain class. This seems like something Spring MVC should be able to, but so far I have only been able to find examples using an html form with only one request param.

Below is my controller and ajax request. Hoping someone can tell me how to map this properly as everything I've tried so far has failed.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/ui/clearBilling',
    type : 'POST',
    data : { "trackId": trackId, "vendorBillingDetails": vendorBillingDetails,  "_csrf": csrf },
    async : true,
    success : function(data) {
            jqAlert("Selected item(s) were cleared");
    },
    fail: function(e) {
        jqAlert("There was an error with the request"); 
    }
});
```

});

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/clearBilling", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String setClearVendorBillingPO(@RequestParam BigInteger trackId, @RequestParam(value = "vendorBillingDetails[]") List<VendorBillingDetail> vendorBillingDetails, HttpServletRequest request) {

    //TODO stuff

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar, but with only sending one json object, so you may have to tweak or wrap it in another object that holds all those request parameters you care about. Try using the @RequestBody annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/clearBilling", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String setClearVendorBillingPO(@RequestBody List<VendorBillingDetail> vendorBillingDetails, HttpServletRequest request) {

//TODO stuff

}
```

In the ajax call, you can use JSON.stringify() (part of json2.js)

```
$.ajax({
        url : "/ui/clearBilling",
        type : "POST",
        async : true, 
        data : JSON.stringify(vendorBillingDetails),
        contentType : "application/json"
    });
```

Comment: Will this work with my other trackId as an input param as well?

Comment: It should work if you create a wrapper object that holds the trackId and vendorBillingDetails.

Comment: I can't say for sure about the separate params though. I would have to change and test mine to see.

Comment: I don't think it works with separate params but the wrapper is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work. Somehow RequestMapping on array of objects ends being error on the receiving end of controller. May be best to try sending as JSON body and then unmarshall in the spring controller.